# Getting independent positioning of li elements in ul

Tags: html, css

Here is the fiddle example of a sidebar that I am trying to incorporate in my website.
http://jsfiddle.net/PF35v/9/

If you hover over the third item, you can notice a sub-menu appearing on hover. 
The sub-menu is written something as follows:

```
<ul id="side-menu">
            <li><img src="http://www.downes.ca/images/RightArrow.gif" alt="sub menu image (assume this is some kind of arrow" style="width:48px; height:48px" />
            </li>
            <li>Sub-menu item 1</li>
            <li>Sub-menu item 2</li>
            <li>Sub-menu item 1</li>
        </ul>
```

where the first `li` item is an image and the other three are text items.

I want to place the `li` items with text independently i.e. these should not come after the first `li` item with image and can be placed in the form as shown in the figure below.

[image]

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could absolutely position all of them. But a better way might be something like this:

```css
#side-menu { margin: 0; padding: 0 0 0 50px; list-style: none; }
#side-menu>li { margin: 0 0 20px; }
#side-menu>li:first-child { float: left; margin: 0 0 0 -50px; }
```

The padding on the left of the `ul` pushes the list items over, and the negative margin combined with the float will pull the arrow back again.

Having said that, there’s an even better way: background images. I’d do something like this:

```css
#side-menu { background: url(/images/RightArrow.gif) no-repeat left; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 0 50px; list-style: none; }
#side-menu>li { margin: 0 0 20px; }
```

and delete the first `li`.